# sorting array of string using qsort

Tags: c

So have an assignment that require me to read an input from a file and sort the input. So if I have a file containing:

```
banana
apple
orange
```

I have sucessfully insert those string to array. the array contain like this:

```
{'b','a','n','a','n','a','\n','a','p','p','l','e','\n','o','r','a','n','g','e'}
```

Now the part that confuse me, is that, I have to use qsort to sort those string. I have create a method that compare two array of char and it works. However, it successfully compare two different string. However, how can I use qsort to sort my array?

Comment: What you wrote doesn't seem an array of strings (char**) but an array of characters (char*)

Comment: That's an array of characters.  Unless your assignment also involves being poked with a hot iron, I'd suggest using standard library strings instead.

Comment: Do you want an array of strings (pointer to multiple `char *`, or `char **`), or an array of characters (pointer to multiple `char`, or `char *`)?

Comment: if I have to make 2D array to hold those string, how can I initialize the array (because the length of each string isn't the same). currently I initialize the array "char* arr = malloc(size+1);" and I get size using st_size in fstat

Comment: 2D array initialisation is in two steps: first you initialise the "array of strings" `char** arrStrings = malloc(numStrings*sizeof(char*));`, then you loop over the "array of strings" and allocate space for each string: `arrStrings[i] = malloc(size + 1);`